# Create windows not showing URL Titanium

Tags: android, titanium

Im trying to make this app, and using a for counter loop for adding the data, but I can't get the addEventListener to open up the .js file. The source path is correct. I verified that from properties!
I tried to do it on an alloy project, but failed, so went back to a traditional project
The code for the app.js file is below:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title: 'Categories',
    exitOnClose: true
});

var data = [];

var categories = [
{title:"Art", url:'app://project 333/Resources/art/artCategory.js'},
{title:"Automotive"},
{title:"Books & Literature"},
{title:"Buildings"},
{title:"Business"},
{title:"Dance"},
{title:"Economy"},
{title:"Education"},
{title:"Fashion"},
{title:"Food"},
{title:"Gardening"},
{title:"Hacking"},
{title:"Health"},
{title:"IT"},
{title:"Military Affairs"},
{title:"Mining"},
{title:"Movies"},
{title:"Music"},
{title:"News"},
{title:"Politics"},
{title:"Sports"},
{title:"Travel"}
];

for (i = 0; i <= categories.length - 1; i++){
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    url: categories[i].url,
    hasChild:true
    });
var rowdata = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: categories[i].title,
    color: '#000',
    font: { fontSize: 24, fontWeight:'Italics', fontFamily:'Helvatica' },
    hasChild:true,
});

row.url = categories[i].url;
row.add(rowdata);
row.categories = categories[i];
data.push(row);
}

var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({});
table.setData(data);

table.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    if (event.row.categories.url){
        var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
            url: event.row.categories.url,
            title: event.row.categories.title,
            _parent: Titanium.UI.currentWindow
        });
        win1.open({
            url: event.row.categories.url
        });
    }
}); 

win.backgroundColor = 'white';
win.add(table);
win.open();
```

Here is the file I am trying to open in the new window:

```
var win1 = Ti.UI.currentWindow({
    title: "Category of Art"
});
win1.backgroundColor = 'white';

var categories = [
{title:"Latest Creations", path:"art/latestCreations/londonartguide.js"},
{title:"Tutorials"},
{title:"Artists"},
{title:"Exhibitions"}
];

var data = [];

for (i = 0; i <= categories.length - 1; i++){
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow();
var rowdata = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: categories[i].title,
    color: '#000',
    font: { fontSize: 24, fontWeight:'Italics', fontFamily:'Helvatica' },
    hasChild:true
});

row.path = categories[i].path;

row.add(rowdata);
row.hasChild = rowdata.hasChild;
data.push(row);
}

var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({});
table.setData(data);

table.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if (e.row.path){
        var nextWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
            path: e.rowData.path,
            title: e.rowData.title
        });
        nextWin.open();
    }
});

win1.add(table);
win1.open();
```

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Also, this is for an android app, so the iphone navigation is out of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES, you need to set path like.

{title:"Art", url:'/art/artCategory.js'}

also in your artCategory.js replace

```
var win1 = Ti.UI.currentWindow({
    title: "Category of Art"
});
```

with

```
var win1 = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
win1.title= "Category of Art";
```

hope it will work

Comment: WORKS PERFECT!!!
Thanks mate!!!
Cant give you rep, coz I dont have enough otherwise I would!
Could you please explain why it didn't work with the title inside Ti.UI.currentWindow???

Comment: @SML Because Ti.UI.currentWindow is a property you can't pass args with it. also [refer](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI-property-currentWindow)

Answer (score 0):

The below path is wrong..

```
app://project 333/Resources/art/artCategory.js
```

you need to set path from your resources folder...like

```
{title:"Art", url:'/art/artCategory.js'}
```

Comment: Upon doing that change, when testing, the new window shows up, with the correct title, but its completely black. Theres nothing on it when it is supposed to be white and have another table. :(. It seems like an odd kind of problem.